# inequality for probability of the sum of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, reference-request

I often use and see the inequality

$P(|X+Y|\leq u) \leq P(|X|\leq 2u)+P(|Y|\geq u)$

for any two r.v. $X$ and $Y$, $u> 0$ etc.

Does anybody know of a reference that I can cite for this? The proof is short and rather elementary, but I thought it would be nice to have a textbook reference.

With many thanks you for your help.

Comment: I've not seen this written down anywhere, so I can't help with a reference request. That said: why not just write the proof down in the context of what you're writing? As you note, the proof is short; it could be delivered as a parenthetical remark of the original statement like, "If $|X + Y| \leq u$, then either $|X| \leq 2u$ or $|Y| \geq u$; hence, $P(|X + Y| \leq u) \leq P(|X| \leq 2u) + P(|Y| \geq u)$. The details can presumably be filled in easily by the reader. If you're concerned they can't, then could you just write and prove a lemma?

Comment: Curious what the "short and elementary" proof is. Please share.

Comment: @ChargeShivers To flesh out what I wrote in my comments a bit: If $|X| > 2u$ and $|Y| < u$, then $2u < |X| \leq |X + Y| + |Y|$ implies that $|X+ Y| > 2u - |Y| \geq u$. Hence, if $|X + Y| \leq u$, we must have that $|X| \leq 2u$ or $|Y| \geq u$, from which it follows that $P(|X + Y| \leq u) \leq P(|X| \leq 2u) + P(|Y| \geq u)$.

Comment: @ChargeShivers, that was my idea as well. Thank you Aaron