# Inequality of probability for the sum of two random variable

Tags: probability

I am in the middle of proving an exercise, and I want to the following statement to be true

> If $X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon$ and $Y_{n}\leq c+\epsilon$, then we have $X_{n}+Y_{n}\leq \epsilon$, so we have the following: $$P(X_{n}+Y_{n}\leq x)\leq P(X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon)+P(Y_{n}<c-\epsilon).$$

But I don't know how to prove the inequality.

It seems that this post [inequality for probability of the sum of 2 random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546107/inequality-for-probability-of-the-sum-of-2-random-variables) is related, but it imposes the absolute value on the sum of random variables.

**My attempt:**

\begin{align*}
P(X_{n}+Y_{n}\leq x)&=P(X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon\ \wedge Y_{n}\leq c+\epsilon)\\
&=P(X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon)+P(Y_{n}\leq c+\epsilon)-P(X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon\ \vee Y_{n}\leq c+\epsilon).
\end{align*}

But this inequality can only give me $$P(X_{n}+Y_{n}\leq x)\geq P(X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon)+P(Y_{n}\leq c+\epsilon),$$ but not the other way.

Also, how to get rid of the equality sign in $P(Y_{n}\leq c+\epsilon)$? I know we can use $$P(Y_{n}>c+\epsilon)=1-P(Y_{n}\leq c+\epsilon),$$ but then again I create $>$ but I need $<$.

I will really appreciate it if anyone can help me...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the inclusion of events.
$$
(X_n+Y_n\leq x)\subset (X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon)\cup(Y_{n}<c-\epsilon)\tag{0}
$$
since if $X_n>x-c+\epsilon$ and $Y_n\geq c-\epsilon$, then $X_n+Y_n>x$. In general, if $A, B$ are events and $A\subset B, $then $P(A)\leq P(B)$ (monotonicity of measure). Applying this fact to $(0)$ yields
$$
P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)\leq P((X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon)\cup(Y_{n}<c-\epsilon))\tag{1}
$$
Also In general if $C, D$ are events then $P(C\cup D)\leq P(C)+P(D)$ (finite subadditivity). Applying this fact to (1) yields the desired result
$$
P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)\leq P(X_{n}\leq x-c+\epsilon)+ P(Y_{n}<c-\epsilon)
$$

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. While I know the measure theory stuff, I missed the basic inclusion of events. Thank you!